# How to test multiple takeEvery in sagas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, redux-saga, redux-saga-test-plan

I have the following saga that listens different type of `action`:

```
export default function *() {
  yield takeEvery('FOO', listener)
  yield takeEvery('BAR', listener2)
  yield takeEvery('HELLO_WORLD', listener3)
}
```

Essentially, this saga has a multiple behavior when it receives certain action.

If it recieves `FOO` as the action type, it will invoke `listener` function, etc.

At the moment, I am having hard time to write test coverage in jest only in these 3 lines.

I thought writing something along with this would work, but no luck:

```
describe('for action type that has "FOO"', () => {
  const actionPayload = {
    type: 'FOO',
  }
  const gen = saga({ type: actionPayload })

  it('listens to "FOO" and yield action', () => {
    const actual = gen.next()
    const expected = takeEvery('FOO', listener)
    expect(actual.value).toEqual(expected)
  })
})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`takeEvery` is actually a `fork`. So you should test like this:

```
describe('for action type that has "SMS_API_REQUEST"', () => {
  const actionPayload = {
    type: 'FOO',
  }
  const gen = saga({ type: actionPayload })

  it('listens to "FOO" and yield action', () => {
    const actual = gen.next()
    const expected = fork(takeEvery, 'FOO', listener)
    expect(actual.value).toEqual(expected)
  })
})
```